# MVC Creating Infragistics grid in strongly-typed View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, infragistics, strongly-typed-view

I have one view (ViewLeads) that only has an Infragistics grid already working and pulling data fine. I have another view (UpdateLead) where I have several textboxes which display the data in the grid when you click on a specific user.

What I want to do is add the infragistics grid to this new view (UpdateLead).  The issue I'm running into is that in my first view(ViewLead) my model reference is...

```
@model IQueryable<LeadManagement.BusinessEntities.BusinessLead>
```

and further down I have my grid like..

```
 @(Html.Infragistics()
            .Grid(Model)
            .ID("grid123")
            .Width("100%")
            .PrimaryKey("Lead_ID")
            .AutoGenerateColumns(false)
            .AutoGenerateLayouts(false)
            .Columns(column =>
            {


                column.For(x => x.Lead_ID).Hidden(true);
                onclick='return true;' />", "Lead_ID", "string", "3%") { Template = "<input type='checkbox' name='select'/>" });
               style='color:blue;'>${Name}</a>").HeaderText("Name").Width("10%");
                style='color:blue;'>${Name}</a>").HeaderText("Name").Width("10%");
                column.For(x => x.Name).Template("<a href='UpdateLead?id=${Lead_ID}' style='color:blue;'>${Name}</a>").HeaderText("Name").Width("10%");
                column.For(x => x.LeadCreationDate).HeaderText("Created").Width("8%");
                column.For(x => x.Source).HeaderText("Source").Width("10%");
                column.For(x => x.status).Template("<a href='#' style='color:blue;'>${status}</a>").HeaderText("Status").Width("10%");
                column.For(x => x.Note).HeaderText("Notes").Width("10%"); 
                column.For(x => x.Litigation).HeaderText("Type of Litigation").Width("12%");
                column.For(x => x.originalFirm).HeaderText("Original Firm").Width("13%");
                column.For(x => x.CurrentFirm).HeaderText("Current Firm").Width("13%");
                column.Columns.Add(new GridColumn("Accept/Deny/Transfer", "Lead_ID", "string", "18%") { Template = "<input type='image' src='/Images/Accept.jpg' height='20' width='20' onclick='return Accepted(${Lead_ID})'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='image' src='/Images/Reject.png' height='20' width='20' onclick='return Rejected(${Lead_ID})'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='image' src='/Images/Transfer.png' height='20' width='20' id='InputAssignLead' onclick='return AssignLead(${Lead_ID})'/>" });
            })
```

NOW...

On my other View (UpdateLead) since I have textboxes and stuff that I'm populating my model reference is..

```
@model LeadManagement.BusinessEntities.BusinessLead
```

and so when I try to copy my Grid code over to this view, it complain about the

```
.Grid(Model)
```

part, saying it has invalid argument, and Vice Versa if I change the model refernce to an Iqueryable reference the textboxes complain.

How can I have both on the same page (textboxes and grid)????  I've tried referencing both model types but that doesn't work either.  I've been stuck on this for a couple days now. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to pass an `IEnumerable<T>` to the `.Grid` parameter - you should just be able to use a `new List<BusinessLead> { Model.BusinessLead }` (i.e. a new list with 1 item which is the lead) - I assume you just want to show one single row in the grid on the Update page? Usually though, I tend to have a `ViewModel` backing up the `View` rather than just using the business model type in question directly - e.g. I'd have an `EditBusinessLeadViewModel` with a property of type `BusinessLead` etc on it and use that in the view - this way you can put behaviour along side your model data

Comment: Charleh, thanks for the reply.  Eventually The new grid on the update page is going to be displaying 'Notes' for that specific user that was selected. But yes for now I'm just trying to get it display basically that one row the selected user.  So you're saying instead of .Grid(Model), do something like .Grid(new List<BusinessLead> ) ?

Comment: Yes, but it depends if that makes sense - it sounds like you have two views, one with a list of leads with buttons to perform operations on a lead, and a view that shows the details for the lead and allows you to edit/update them. On this screen it sounds like you want to show a grid with just the lead that the user selected on the previous page. If so you can just wrap the single lead in a collection type (something that supports `IEnumerable` such as `List<T>` like I suggested) and pass that to the grid. It will only contain 1 item but it will satisfy the grids need for a collection type

Answer (score 1):

There could appear such problem when you didn't mentioned:

```
@using Infragistics.Web.Mvc
```

and your model like in example below

```
@using IgniteUI.SamplesBrowser.Models

    @model IQueryable<IgniteUI.SamplesBrowser.Models.Northwind.Product>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined CSS Files -->
    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2016.2/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2016.2/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined JavaScript Files -->
    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2016.2/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2016.2/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
        @(Html.Infragistics()
            .Grid(Model)
            .ID("grid")
            .Width("100%")
            .Height("500px")
            .PrimaryKey("ID")
            .AutoGenerateColumns(false)
            .AutoGenerateLayouts(false)
            .Columns(column =>
            {
                column.For(x => x.ProductName).HeaderText("Product Name").Width("30%");
                column.For(x => x.CategoryName).HeaderText("Category").Width("30%");
                column.For(x => x.UnitPrice).HeaderText("Unit Price").Width("20%");
                column.For(x => x.UnitsInStock).HeaderText("Units In Stock").Width("20%");
            })
            .Features(features =>
            {
                features.Sorting().Type(OpType.Remote);
                features.Paging().Type(OpType.Remote);
                features.Filtering().Type(OpType.Remote);
                features.Responsive().ColumnSettings(cs =>
                {
                    cs.ColumnSetting().ColumnKey("CategoryName").Classes("ui-hidden-phone");
                    cs.ColumnSetting().ColumnKey("UnitPrice").Classes("ui-hidden-phone ui-hidden-tablet");
                });
            })
            .DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("GetProducts"))
            .Render()
        )
    </body>
    </html>
```

http://www.igniteui.com/grid/_ga=1.235256967.729368916.1477415519